# pinia store from fetched data seems not reactive

Tags: vue.js, async-await, vue-router, pinia

I am doing a little exercise with Vue, Pinia and Router and I am facing problems with retreiving data from a simple json-server
I'll try to explain myself as shortly as possible:

Let's say my store config (simplified) is:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import {fetchTasks} from '../utils/utils.js'

const SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:3001";

export const useTaskStore  = defineStore('taskStore', {
    state: () => ({
        tasks: [],
        singletask: []
    }),
    getters: {
        },

    },
    actions: {
        async getTasks() {
            this.tasks = await fetchTasks(`${SERVER_URL}/tasks`) 
        },

        async getSingleTask(id) {
            this.singletask = await fetchTasks(`${SERVER_URL}/tasks/${id}`);   
        }
    }
  })
```

Function fetchTask in utils is simply:

```
const fetchTasks = async (url) => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(url);
      const data = await res.json();
      return data;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
};
```

The response for e.g. http://localhost:3001/tasks is something like:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "First Task"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Second Task"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Third Task"
  }
]
```

while the response for e.g. http://localhost:3001/tasks/1 is something like:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "First Task"
}
```

The component for the list of tasks is:

```
<script setup>

import TaskItemComponent from './TaskItem.vue'
import { useTaskStore } from '@/stores/taskStore'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
const taskStore = useTaskStore();
const {tasks}  = storeToRefs(taskStore);
</script>
<template>
    <div class="max-w-5xl mx-auto">
        <template>      
            <TaskItemComponent v-for="t, index in tasks" 
                :key = "index"
                :task = "t"
                />       
        </template>
    </div> 
</template>
```

and the TaskItemComponent component:

```
<script setup>
import { useTaskStore } from '@/stores/taskStore'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

const props = defineProps(
    {task: {type: Object} }
)
const taskStore = useTaskStore();
const router = useRouter();

const handleClick = () => {      
    router.push({name:'taskdetail',params:{'id':props.task.id}}) 
}
</script>
<template>
    <div class="flex flex-row gap-2 bg-green-100 hover:bg-green-300 m-4 p-4 rounded-md cursor-pointer" @click="handleClick">
        <h3>{{ task.title}}</h3>
        <p class="text-xs">(id:{{ task.id }})</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

And so far everything works fine.

The problem arises when I click on a "task item" to kick in the 'taskdetail' route - I want to fill the data fetched using the function getSingleTask

So far I wrote  on the component for the task detail

```
<script setup>
    import {onMounted,toRefs} from 'vue';
    import { useTaskStore } from '@/stores/taskStore';
    import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'; 
    import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
    
    const taskStore = useTaskStore();   
    const {singletask}  = storeToRefs(taskStore)
    const router = useRouter();
    const props = defineProps(['id'])
    const {id} = toRefs(props);

    const getTask = (id) => {
        taskStore.getSingleTask(id);
        console.log(taskStore.singletask.id)        
        if (!taskStore.singletask.id) {
                router.replace({name:'notfound'})
        }           
    }
    onMounted(()=>{
        getTask(id.value); 
    })
</script>
<template>
<div class="max-w-5xl mx-auto p-8">
    <template v-if="singletask.id">
        <div class="mt-4 p-4 bg-red-300 text-xl font-bold rounded-t-xl">
            ID:{{singletask.id}}
        </div>
        <div class="flex p-4 bg-green-200 h-96 items-center text-center align-middle rounded-b-xl">
            {{singletask.title}}
        </div>
       
    </template>    
</div>
</template>
```

where is the problem? The fist time I click on a task the app goes 404 because the value of 'taskStore.singletask.id' is undefined (checked from the console.log)
I've understood that each time I click, the value of the id is the previous one clicked.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong

Thanks for the help, tell me if you need further info.

Comment: You are loading singletask inside a async function, so initially the single task id is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `taskdetail` route the `getSingleTask` is called and before the completion of it you are trying to access the single task.

Try adding `await`  before `taskStore.getSingleTask(id)` and make the `getTask` to be an async function. (or do it with `then .. catch`)

You could give loading message in `singletask` state.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now it works.

```     
 const getTask = async (id) => {
        await taskStore.getSingleTask(id)
        if (!taskStore.singletask) {
                router.replace({name:'notfound'})
        }           
    }
```